# Would this be an even or odd function?

Tags: functions, elementary-functions, even-and-odd-functions

Given that $f(x)$ is odd, I need to find if $f(\sec x)$ is odd.

We (or I, at least) have always defined an odd function in the following way: $f(x)$ is odd if $f(x)=-f(-x)$, for all $x$ in the domain of $f(x)$.

Since $f(\sec x)$ is defined in terms of $\sec x$ should I be checking if $f(\sec x)=f(-\sec x)$ or $f(x)=f(-x)$?

I think the former, but not according to my textbook — and there's no solution given to this problem so I'm not convinced why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $f(x)=f(-x)$ is for even, not odd.

Comment: You can also assume f(x) to be x.(Meanwhile correcting your defintion of odd function)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the definition of odd function is: for each $x\in D_f$, $f(-x)=-f(x)$. In particular, since your function is $f\circ\sec$, asserting that it is odd means that$$(\forall x\in D_{f\circ\sec}):f\bigl(\sec(-x)\bigr)=-f\bigl(\sec(x)\bigr).$$But, in fact, your function is even, since $\sec$ is even, and therefore, if $x\in D_{f\circ\sec}$, then $f\bigl(\sec(-x)\bigr)=f\bigl(\sec(x)\bigr)$.

Comment: I do not think this answer addresses OP's main problem here.

Comment: @chocolateMousse I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Actually, my question is this: if $f(x)$ is odd if $f(x)=-f(-x)$,  analogously, shouldn't $f(secx)$ be odd if $f(secx)=- f(-secx)$, if you get what I mean.(This is because $f(secx)$ is a function of $secx$ and not $x$)

Comment: You must see $f\circ\sec$ as a single *thing*. Call it $g$. And asserting that $g$ is odd is the same thing as asserting that, for each $x$ in its domain, $g(-x)=-g(x)$. So, asserting that $f\circ\sec$ is odd is the same thing as asserting that, for each $x$ in its domain, $f\bigl(\sec(-x)\bigr)=-f\bigl(\sec(x)\bigr)$. And this is not true (unless $f$ happens to be equal to $0$ on the range of $\sec$).